# how i passed the message when i submit the form on zend framework1

Tags: php, json, zend-framework

I have this script action in My controller :

```
if($user->editUser($data)) {
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            "response"  =>  true,
            "message"   =>  "L'utilisateur " . $data['lastnameUser'] 
                            . " " . $data['firstnameUser'] . "a été modifié"
        )
    );
    exit(); 
} else {
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            "response"     => false,
            "errorMessage" => "Il y a eu une erreur dans l'edition de l'utilisateur."
        )
    );
    exit();
}
```

And in my index.phtml I have an icon for update, I want when I update, show this message "message"

```
"L'utilisateur " . $data['lastnameUser'] . " " . $data['firstnameUser'] . "a été modifié"));
```

i do that but not work ;

```
$('#editUser').submit(function(event)
{
    var formId = $(this).attr('id');


    var data = {
        // user's properties 
        genderUser              :       $("#genderUser").val(),

        langUser                :       $("select[name='langUser']").val(),
        rankUser                :       $("#rankUser").val()
    };  

    $.ajax({
        url: $('#'+formId).attr('action'),
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)
        {                    
            if (data.response == true)
            {
                alert(data.message);

            }
            else
            {
```

Thanks in advance for you .

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. You wish to perform an AJAX request that populates your update with the above message?

Comment: yes how can i do that please ,thanks in advance

Comment: Provide some more details so that it's easy to answer.

Comment: i want to show this message if i do update on .phtml thanks in advance

Comment: Are you loading a new site? Then just add the message to your view. Or do you use AJAX? Then JavaScript is your weapon of choice.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your question is just about how to pass values from the Controller to the View.

In the controller, you can to it like this

```
if($user->editUser($data))
{
    $this->view->output= array(
        "response"  =>  true,
        "message"   =>  "L'utilisateur " . $data['lastnameUser'] . " " 
                        . $data['firstnameUser'] . "a été modifié"
    );
}else{
    $this->view->output = array(
        "response" => false,
        "errorMessage" => "Il y a eu une erreur dans l'edition de l'utilisateur."
    );
}
```

In your view you can access these values like

```
if($this->output['response'] === true) {
    echo $this->output['message'];
} else {
    echo $this->output['errorMessage'];
}
```

There might be smarter ways to do it, but this should be a working example close to the code you provided.